# Wordpress theme development for a big site

Tags: wordpress, testing, themes

I am developing a theme for a site usign wordpress as a cms. The site has already more than 2000 posts. I am working locally on my computer and trying to simulate the post types etc here. Almost done. But I am very scared to upload and activate the new theme I have been developing locally.

What is the best way to test it and see everything is OK and be sure that I am on the safe side.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking exactly here but what you should be doing is testing it in an environment that's the same as your production environment. In other words, same operating system version, same web server version, same PHP version, same MYSQL version, etc.

Comment: What I am trying to ask here is what's the checklist before activating the new theme

Comment: @OnurÇelik that is acutally a pretty good question: I think you should incorporated that comment into your question